# Passar uma variável de uma função para outra

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Eai gente, beleza? Seguinte, como eu poderia fazer para enviar a variável`mts_quadrados` da `def prog( )` para ser calculada na `def prog_main( )`?

```
def prog():
    print("Informe o valor: ")
    cli()
    mts_quadrados = int(input(":"))
    clr()

def prog_main():
    qtd_lata = int(mts_quadrados / 6)
    vlr_lata = float(qtd_lata * 80)
```

Comment: Você quer enviar a variável "mts_quadrados"?

Answer (score 7):

## Passar como parametro

Você pode colocar a variável "mts_quadrados" como parâmetro na função "prog_main" e depois passar a função "prog" como parâmetro para "prog_main" e colocar o retorno de "prog" a variável "mts_quadrados", como no exemplo abaixo:

```
def prog():
    print("Informe o valor: ")
    cli()
    mts_quadrados = int(input(":"))
    clr()
    return mts_quadrados # retorna o valor 

def prog_main(mts_quadrados):
    qtd_lata = int(mts_quadrados / 6)
    vlr_lata = float(qtd_lata * 80)

prog_main(prog()) # o retorno de "prog" e passado como parâmetro para "prog_main"
```

## Usar a palavra reservada global

Usando a palavra reservada `global` no começo da função o Python entende que aquela variável é de escopo global.

```
mts_quadrados = 0

def prog():
    global mts_quadrados
    print("Informe o valor: ")
    cli()
    mts_quadrados = int(input(":"))
    clr()

def prog_main():
    global mts_quadrados
    qtd_lata = int(mts_quadrados / 6)
    vlr_lata = float(qtd_lata * 80)
```

[Como usar uma variável global numa função diferente da que a criou?](https://blog.liveedu.tv/python-como-usar-variavel-global-numa-funcao/)

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um return com os `mts_quadrados` dentro do `prog()`

```
def prog():
    print("Informe o valor: ")

    mts_quadrados = int(input(":"))

    return mts_quadrados
```

e no `prog_main()` dizes logo que a `qtd_lata` é igual ao que vem de `prog()` a dividir por 6

```
def prog_main():
    qtd_lata = int(prog() / 6)
    vlr_lata = float(qtd_lata * 80)
```

Answer (score -3):

Como tudo no python é um objeto, funções ñ poderiam ser diferentes

```
def envia(arg):
    recebe.valor = arg

def recebe():
   print(recebe.valor)

>>> envia(2)
>>> recebe()
2
```

Comment: essa sugestão e uma das piores formas possíveis de se fazer o que a pergunta pede.
A forma correta de se passa valores entre funções é pela passagem de parâmetros e valores de retorno.

Comment: Podemos fazer todas as coisas com Python, mas nem todas as coisas são lícitas ... Venhamos e convenhamos, da uma olha na seção de DOCS no site do Python pra obter maiores informações amigo.
Segue link: https://www.python.org/doc/